# What are the implications of SHA-1 collision for other hash functions like RIPEMD-160?

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha

Given that SHA-1 collision was proven, what are the implications for other hash functions using the same digest size, specifically for RIPEMD-160?
It is still relatively safe, or should it be replaced with RIPEMD-256 or SHA-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHA-1 collision was based on some weakness of the SHA-1 hash. This is what makes it *100,000 faster than the brute force attack*.[¹](https://shattered.it/) Different hash functions will probably not have the same issue, although I would make plans for replacing them.